# Change color of <td> independetly in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have three `<td>` inside a table. I want to change color of the `<td>` independently. onClick , a Modal pops up and you can select the color. Right now , when I set the color on state, all the `<td>` change their background color. I want to change the color of each `<td>` independently. So one `<td>` might have red, other `<td>` will have green and other `<td>` will have yellow .

```
 state = { visible: false, color: "", text: ""  };
     showModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: true
    });
  };
     boxes1 = (value, text) => {
        console.log("dssdf", value);
        this.setState(
          {
            color: value,
            text: text
          },
          () => console.log("this is wt", this.state.color)
        );
      };

      boxes2 = (value, text) => {
        console.log("vf", value);
        this.setState(
          {
            color: value,
            text: text
          },
          () => console.log("this is wt", this.state.color)
        );
      };

      boxes3 = (value, text) => {
        console.log("sds", value);
        this.setState(
          {
            color: value,
            text: text
          },
          () => console.log("this is wt", this.state.color)
        );
      };

     render() {
        const yellow = "yellow";
        const blue = "blue";
        const reenter code hered = "red";
        const text = "colors";

        let s = [1, 2, 3];

        let d = s.map(tables => (
          <div>
            <table
              style={{
                border: "1px solid black",
                width: "70px",
                background: `${this.state.color}`
              }}
            >
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <td onClick={this.showModal}>{this.state.text}Change 
                   colors
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </div>
        ));
     return (
          <div>
            {d}
            <Modal
              title="Basic Modal"
              visible={this.state.visible}
              onOk={this.handleOk}
              onCancel={this.handleCancel}
            >
              <div className="boxes" onClick={()=>this.boxes1(yellow,text)}>
               YELLOW
              </div>
              <div className="boxes" onClick={() => this.boxes2(red,text)}>
               RED
              </div>
              <div className="boxes" onClick={() => this.boxes3(blue,text)}>
               BLUE
              </div>
            </Modal>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Expected : When clicked on a single `<td>` the background color should update only for that `<td>` update.

Actual: When clicked, the background color for all the `<td>` is changed

Comment: I can see single td in code but the click is trigger from different div , so you want to change color of div with classname boxes or that single td?

Comment: The single td is mapped 3 times, so this creates three td's[boxes], What I want to do is , onClick on a  single td , i would need to change the background color of that td only.

Comment: **Have three td inside a table** It should be: _Has td in each three tables_

Answer (score 1):

We must have multiple item to represent multiple `div` element else it will be fail as yours i.e, changing all `div` color.
Following is the code:

```
state = { box1: {visible: false, color: "", text: ""},
box2: {visible: false, color: "", text: ""},
box3: {visible: false, color: "", text: ""},  };

     showModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: true
    });
  };
   boxesChange = (value, text, id) => {
    const box={
            color: value,
            text: text
          };        
    this.setState(
          `${id}`:box,
          () => console.log("this is wt", this.state.color)
        );
      };

     render() {
        const yellow = "yellow";
        const blue = "blue";
        const reenter code hered = "red";
        const text = "colors";

        let s = [1, 2, 3];

        let d = s.map(tables => (
          <div>
            <table
              style={{
                border: "1px solid black",
                width: "70px",
                background: `${this.state.color}`
              }}
            >
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <td onClick={this.showModal}>{this.state.text}Change 
                   colors
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </div>
        ));
     return (
          <div>
            {d}
            <Modal
              title="Basic Modal"
              visible={this.state.visible}
              onOk={this.handleOk}
              onCancel={this.handleCancel}
            >
              <div id="box1" className="boxes" onClick={()=>this.boxes1(yellow,text,id)}>
               YELLOW
              </div>
              <div id="box2" className="boxes" onClick={() => this.boxes2(red,text,id)}>
               RED
              </div>
              <div id="box3" className="boxes" onClick={() => this.boxes3(blue,text,id)}>
               BLUE
              </div>
            </Modal>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: thank you @imrajshah. So i would need  multiple items to change different elements.
This creates another problem. I need to create around 80 td's like these and this would make the state component huge.So I think we would have to loop through the state. Is that correct?

Comment: So you can create array of box in state, and then add all your <td> in that. It will solve your problem

Comment: Getting an error here:

this.setState(
          `${id}`:box,
          () => console.log("this is wt", this.state.color)
        );
      };


the id property in setState is giving me an error

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion for dynamic style render based on index of element :

Assuming that you have rendered multiple element below is just an example to apply dynamic style to element based on index of element which is clicked that particular element style can be changed :

Pseudo code :

```
const myStyleBackgroundColor = {};

allElementArray.map((item,index)=>
<div onClick={(e)=>onClickHandle(index)} style={{backgroundColor : myStyleBackgroundColor[index] ? myStyleBackgroundColor[index] : "#FFF" }}>
This is the div which will change color once clicked based on index
</div>
);

onClickHandle(index){
myStyleBackgroundColor [index] = "color";
// apply rest of index a default color
}
```

Note : Above constant can be a variable array in local state also.